# Question about code execution and the nature of javascript blocking/ non blocking

Tags: javascript, mysql, performance, blocking

Basically I have something similar to the code below and I'm not entirely sure what order of execution is always going to happen. Right now I suppose it executes in a non blocking fashion, being

```
func() -> self.db.createEntry() -> res.on() -> callback -> self.submit()
```

But I've had times that it's

```
func() -> self.db.createEntry() -> callback -> res.on() -> self.submit()
```

I have no control over when `res.on('data')` is called because it is a socket event listener and is handled on a separate server. I guess that I'm afraid that the callback is going to be called in the middle of `res.on()` is that something that could happen? Say `res.on()` is right in the middle of execution would the callback be able to interrupt that?

```js
const func = function(){

self.db.createEntry(self.arg, self.arg1, function(response){
    if(response){
        self.arg = response
        self.state.wait = false
        if(self.state.wait){
            self.submit()
        }
    }
});

res.on('data', function(data) {
    data = parse(data);
    if(!data.contentId){
        self.state.wait = true;
        self.state.data = data
    }
    else {
        self.submit(data);
    }
});

}

func()

db.prototype.createEntry = function(arg, arg1, callback) {
    self.connect();
    self.connection.query('INSERT INTO table_name SET ?', arg, function(err, results, fields) {
        if(err) {
            self.disconnect();
            callback()
        }
        else {    
            self.disconnect();
            callback(results)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's event so it's normal that it run in parallel. If you want order, maybe you should design it another way to have more control of the IO. Like instead of execute the code directly, putting the execution chain on a stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for JavaScript code to *switch midway* in a function is because of a `yield` instruction.

Your current function doesn't include such.

`yield` is also rarely used. Instead we use callbacks (`async`/`await` code are callbacks on steroids—syntax sugar making it a lot easier to write code without a ton a inline functions used to handle a long chain of callbacks and much easier way to handle errors too).

The `self.submit()` will generate such a callback, but the `res.on()` itself is not going to *stop midway*.

Keep in mind that JavaScript is still event driven and it does not use multiple threads. So only one function is executed at a time.

If the order (`callback -> res.on()` or `res.on() -> callback`) does not matter, then you're good to go.

Comment: I understand that res.on() isn't going to just stop but it sounds like callback and res.on() could run side by side which I don't want

Comment: There is no multi-threading, so they will run one after the other. The order, however, could vary. If that's okay, then you're set.

Comment: Nailed it with "JavaScript is still event driven and it does not use multiple threads" exactly what I was looking for, thank you :)